# Can't Press Multiple keys at the same time

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hp-laptop

When I first purchased this laptop and install some games I was able to hold w and press 2 on my keyboard at the same time to select my 2nd inventory slot but now when I try to hold w and tap 2 it doesn't works even with holding a i cant press 1 to select my 1st inventory slot in games, can anyone help me get rid of this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tested what keys you can press at the same time? https://www.mechanical-keyboard.org/key-rollover-test/

Comment: Run hardware diagnostics on your computer. Try DISM from an Admin command prompt.  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth